# How to get the actual type in the body of a generic function?

Tags: java, generics, type-parameter

Here is the code:

```
public <K, T> Map<K, T> method1(Map<K, T> map, Class<T> entityClass){
    //I need the Class instance of the actual type T here; 
    String name = entityClass.getClass().getName();
    return map;
}
```

Is that `entityClass` parameter in `method1` redundant? Can I get that info from the map instance passed to this function?

Like this:

```
public <K, T> Map<K, T> method2(Map<K, T> map){
    //Can I get T's actual type without that additonal parameter `Class<T> entityClass` ?
    //I think this information is alreay provided by the map instance passed in by the caller.
    //But I don't know how or even whether it is possible.
    return map;
}
```

Comment: No, it's erased. That's why you resort to workarounds like this in Java.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `entityClass` parameter is necessary. All the generic type information is thrown away at compile time. (This is called [*Type Erasure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).) In the bytecode generated by the compiler, all generic types are replaced by their bounds or by `Object` if they are unbounded (as are `K` and `T` in the code you posted).

It is not possible to recover this discarded information at run time. This is why an extra type parameter like `entityClass` is always used when actual type information is needed.

Comment: Can't he use something like `map.values().iterator().next().getClass()`? Ofcourse, assuming that his `map` has some valid entries.

Comment: @Codebender - First, that won't work at all if the map is empty or if it is storing a `null` value. Second, even if there is a value there, that idiom will only get you the class of the actual object stored. This may have very little to do with the actual type to which the generic type has been bound. (For instance, `T` may have been bound to an interface type, not a class.)